# Can we change the sequence of json items?

Tags: arrays, json, sequence

Can we change the sequence of json items?
For example:

```
[
{
        "category": "Science: Mathematics",
        "type": "multiple",
        "difficulty": "medium",
        "question": "In a complete graph G, which has 12 vertices, how many edges are there?",
        "correct_answer": "66",
        "incorrect_answers1": "67",
        "incorrect_answers2 : "34",
        "incorrect_answers3 : "11"

    },
    {
        "category": "Science: Mathematics",
        "type": "multiple",
        "difficulty": "medium",
        "question": "In base 2, what is 1 + 1?",
        "incorrect_answers1": "2",
        "incorrect_answers2 : "01",
        "correct_answer": "10",
        "incorrect_answers3 : "11"
    },
    {
        "category": "Science: Mathematics",
        "type": "multiple",
        "difficulty": "medium",
        "question": "In the hexadecimal system, what number comes after 9?",
        "incorrect_answers1": "10",
        "incorrect_answers2 : "The Number 0",
        "correct_answer": "The Letter A",
        "incorrect_answers3 : "16"
    }
]
```

Comment: It's not possible and neither required. You can only change the position of items in an array. May I know your requirements i.e. why you need to do this?

Comment: Could you please show your expected output and state why you would like to do so ? May be, there are better solutions that suits your need that just reordering the json.

Comment: The [JSON standard](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) states *An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs.*, so you really shouldn't care about property order.  But if you must, some JSON serializers allow this, others don't.  You have tagged this [tag:json.net] which is a JSON serializer for [tag:c#]/[tag:.net].  Are you using this library to serialize .Net objects to JSON?  Can you share a [mcve] showing how you are serializing your JSON currently?

Comment: I am creating an android app of quiz in which I am using json raw file for quiz data. I do not want to have the same sequence for correct answers. I have mentioned my requirement in the code. In json object, correct_answer is in option A. In 2nd object, correct_answer is option C. In 3rd object, correct_answer is option C. I want this type of result. Is it possible?

Comment: Please let me know if my answers was helpful.

Comment: I understood. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments that re-ordering JSON data is impossible and also not required.

For the current situation, you have to loop across the parent array containing the JSON objects, create a local array variable to get the list of re-ordered answers, push all the answers to this array and shuffle it using a library like lodash (https://lodash.com/docs/#shuffle) or a custom random functions, whatever works for your needs.

You can place this array within each object of this JSON while looping and give it a meaningful key like `shuffled_answers`.

So now your item structure will look like this:

```
{
  "category": "Science: Mathematics",
  "type": "multiple",
  "difficulty": "medium",
  "question": "In base 2, what is 1 + 1?",
  "incorrect_answers1": "2",
  "incorrect_answers2" : "01",
  "correct_answer": "10",
  "incorrect_answers3" : "11",
  "shuffled_answers": ["2", "11", "10", "11"]
}
```

You can then use this array to display answer choices in your UI to ask user the question and use the `correct_answer` key to compare the correct answer from the user's choice.

I'm linking [here](https://youtu.be/4deVCNJq3qc?list=PL3se4ISKCVdtMzQUNNq-JsxCAay3VnvMP&t=5030) a video tutorial for a very similar App developed in Vue using the above logic. You can refer for more insight about apps like these and use it for your requirements.

Hope that helps.